# Why some electrons in ESR aligned their spin towards external magnetic and some against

Tags: quantum-spin, electrons, spectroscopy

Why some electrons in [ESR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_paramagnetic_resonance) aligned their spin towards magnetic field and some against?

Answer (score 1):

> Why some electrons in ESR aligned their spin towards magnetic field and some against?

There is a [Boltzmann distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_distribution) between the parallel and antiparallel states. At room temperature, there is only a tiny excess of the lower energy state. This is why liquid nitrogen or liquid helium is used to get a more favorable population difference between the two states.

The electron spin being anti-parallel to the applied field, meaning the magnetic moment is parallel to the applied field given the negative charge of the electron, is the lower energy state.  In other words, the $m_s = -1/2$ state is the lower energy state.

See [Electron Paramagnetic Resonance Spectroscopy](http://www.life.illinois.edu/crofts/pdf_files/Dikanov_Crofts_EPR_review_Chapter-3-2006.pdf) for more information.